# How to add a culture to RegionInfo without upgrading OS?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, culture

I am attempting to match an ISO-3166 compliant two-letter country abbreviation with System.Globalization.RegionalInfo and have come across an issue preventing me from getting the values for Ghana and Liberia.

When running

```
new System.Globalization.RegionInfo("GH").Dump();
```

on LINQPad 5 on my Windows 7 machine in order to get regional information on Ghana, I get an ArgumentException saying

```
Culture name 'GH' is not supported.Parameter name: name
```

When running the same code on LINQPad 5 on my colleague's machine that runs Windows 10, I get a proper response with all the values I need.

As far as I understand, RegionalInfo uses the computer's culture information in order to match the values correctly, which would explain this odd behaviour. Assuming this is the reason as to why we get different responses, is there any way to add additional cultures without needing to upgrade the OS?

Comment: Are the machines running the same version of .NET?

Comment: The Windows 7 machine uses 4.6.01055 while the Windows 10 machine uses 4.6.01590. Not sure if this minor difference is also because of the OS.

Comment: Looks like it's an OS difference then. The MSDN pages on RegionInfo didn't mention any restrictions that I could see. They reference external resources for the list of supported names etc.